# How to check mailbox size without exchange module?

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, adsi

I need to find a way to check mailbox size and items count under PowerShell, but without using exchange snapin/module.

Normally this command would look like this:

```
Get-MailboxStatistics "XXX" | ft TotalItemSize, ItemCount
```

My goal is to checked those things without exchange specific commands. I don't have much knowledge about ADSI, but maybe this is the key to solve this.

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: I think there's none, as you have to query against an Exchange database to get mailbox size.

Comment: Why do you need to do this without Exchange? You can just connect to an exchange session from your own machine.

Comment: Are you using Outlook" http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/05/26/use-powershell-to-data-mine-your-outlook-inbox.aspx You can use this to get the size

Comment: The reason why I am trying to do this, is because this should be a part of larger script. Client don't want to allow me and my colleagues use Exchange shell. I don't know why, but that's just the way it is. Of course I can check this manually on EMC, but this is a lot more time consuming.

Thanks Matt, but this is going to be used on server environment for a larger group of people, not just for me.

Comment: I believe you can get some of that info using Exchange Web Services (EWS) http://gsexdev.blogspot.com/2014/08/getting-folder-sizes-and-other-stats.html